# Weird incremented query result in a while

Tags: php, sql, while-loop, increment

I don't understand why the result of the '$taille' array begin to the key [1] instead of key [0]?
 So it s displaying 3 results instead of 4 (occulting the first result)...

```
<?php 
$req = $bdd->prepare('SELECT size FROM tailles_produits WHERE id_produit = ?');
$req->execute(array($_GET['id']));
$donnees = $req->fetch();

$numb_taille = array();
$taille = array();
$i = 0;
while($donnees = $req->fetch())
{
    $i++;
    $taille[$i] = $donnees['size'];
    $numb_taille['total'] = $i;
}
$total = $numb_taille['total'];

echo '<pre>';
print_r ($taille);
echo '</pre>';

$req->closeCursor();
?>
```

Which gives

```
ARRAY
(
    [1] => S
    [2] => M
    [3] => L
)
```

Instead of

```
ARRAY
(
    [1] => XS
    [2] => S
    [3] => M
    [4] => L
)
```

Can anyone help me with this pleas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you have an extra

```
$donnees = $req->fetch();
```

statement before the loop that fills in `$taille`. So the data from the first row is being fetched but not stored in the array.

Comment: Yeah! I didn't saw your answer in time, but I've found the answer too. 
Thanks a lot.

Comment: You accepted an answer, that's the closest SO has to "solved".

Answer (score 1):

PHP arrays start with 0, so all you need to do is move your `i++` down until after you're done using the data from that index

```
<?php 
$req = $bdd->prepare('SELECT size FROM tailles_produits WHERE id_produit = ?');
$req->execute(array($_GET['id']));
$donnees = $req->fetch();

$numb_taille = array();
$taille = array();
$i = 0;
while($donnees = $req->fetch())
{
    $taille[$i] = $donnees['size'];
    $numb_taille['total'] = $i;
    $i++; //iterate after your calculations are done
}
$total = $numb_taille['total'];

echo '<pre>';
print_r ($taille);
echo '</pre>';

$req->closeCursor();
?>
```

Comment: Thanks for your fast answers too. It works, but it's still displaying only 3 results even if it starts at key [0]...?

Comment: @Decay your while loop should compare i to the record count in your query

Comment: It appears that I called "$donnees = $req -> fetch();" twice.<br/>
I just erased the first call.

Answer (score 0):

It is because you increment $i before using it as a key for the new array item.

Do the increment at the end of your while loop.

Comment: Thanks for your fast answers, now it starts to run from key [0], but it display only 3 results anyway...?